What is the reasoning behind putting table and figures at the very end of submitted papers?
Sometimes papers I receive for review will not have the tables and figures placed in the text body where the are referenced, but instead at the very end after the bibliography. I personally find that extremly irritating, as I have to scroll back and forth from the spot where a table or figure is mentioned in the text to the page where they are actually displayed. This is not only inconvenient, but makes it also more difficult to assess the completeness and accuracy of data displayed, the overall quality of the figures and images etc.
As a reviewer, I really cannot find any positive aspect for this structure, but sure enough it is not only accepted at some journals, but sometimes even actively encouraged. Why is this the case?

Bad editorial management systems, that's what ...

At some point the journal has to typeset it for real, and does want them separate so a professional can do the proper job.

@JonCuster That I understand, but this could totally be done when I final version after the review process is handed in

So who puts in and then properly pulls out all the stuff? An accepted paper needs the separated bits, so start with that goal in mind. That it is an issue for some people’s work flow is pretty irrelevant. I just put all that stuff in a separate window.

@JonCuster An easy solution is to put tables and figures into the text where the belong-ish, and send them as well as separate files (also to not have problems with resolution when figures are put in the text only). And many, many journals have word or latex templates these days where you are supposed to place the figures and tables.

Look, I get it - this is a somewhat archaic practice. Changing a journal's workflow requires time and money and introduces risk into the process, so they don't do it. Just like a dozen other bureaucratic systems you interact with daily.

Just a minor comment: If you're reading papers digitally and all the figures/tables are at the end, just open the document in 2 different PDF viewer windows one way or another. One of them is your reading version, the other is scrolled to the figures/tables so you can click back and forth.

@Fe2O3 publishing scientific articles is one of the most lucrative businesses there is, with much of the work done by unpaid volunteers (e.g. the review). I truly don't think the "cost" of making the review process smoother would really impact the already thousands of dollars you already have to pay at some journals to get published. Elsevier had some 40% profit margins in the past, the could live with 39 and have one more editor on their payroll.

This is a hangover from earlier times, when graphical material would likely need to be produced and printed using different systems to the main text. Thus, the format is designed to support manual collation of all the pieces.
Some people argue that it is useful for review purposes to have the figures separate from the main text, so that you can easily lay them out (in printed form) and refer to them as you read the manuscript. Personally, I have never been convinced that this is as big an advantage as the advocates claim.

Who even still reads the printed-out version of the manuscript?

I'll chime in as someone who sometimes prints out papers. When you actually care about what they're saying (e.g. you're trying to implement a system they propose but don't implement), it can be really nice to print out all the figures on paper for reference while you read the prose. Sadly, I've never seen a modern paper collect its figures the way OP is asking about.

@WolfgangBangerth I tend to print papers I need to read carefully, including papers I'm reviewing or proofreading. Being able to use a red pen somehow makes it easier to be thorough :) But I would staple the pages together anyway for ease of transportation, so this laying out the figures argument doesn't really appeal to me.

The modern version of laying it out printed would possibly be viewing on two monitors. But I still find it clunky.
